# A difficulty in understanding the proof of completeness of $l_{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, complete-spaces

A part of the proof is given in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I do not understand why equation(2) & (3) is right, could anyone explain this for me please?

ِAlso, I did not understand the idea used in the last paragraph starting from $sup ||x_{n}|| = M,$ could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: A very smart and detailed explanation for completeness of $l_{p}$ is found in this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096253/problems-with-the-proof-that-ellp-is-complete/1101556#1101556

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2): we have $\xi_k^{(n)} \to \xi_k$ as $n \to \infty$, hence

$ \sum_{k=1}^j |\xi_k^{(n)}|^2 \to \sum_{k=1}^j |\xi_k|^2$ as $n \to \infty$.

(3) $ \sum_{k=1}^j |\xi_k^{(n)}|^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\xi_k^{(n)}|^2=||x_n||^2.$

Comment: Thank you, it is so clear, what about the 3 lines after equation(3), I also did not understand them, could u clarify them please, if you have time?

Comment: Did the author used the idea of "increasing sequence and bounded above so it is convergent" ?