# Question in $l^p$ proof

Tags: functional-analysis

In Kreyszig's proof ([*Functional analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471504599)) that $l^p$ is complete, one defines a Cauchy sequence such that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $m,n>N$ s.t. $(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|\xi_j^{(m)}-\xi_j^{(n)}|)^{1/p}$ ($x_m=(\xi_1^{(m)},\xi_2^{(m)},\dots)$). This implies $|\xi_j^{(m)}-\xi_j^{(n)}|<\epsilon$ for all $j$. From here one can conclude $\xi_j^{(m)}\rightarrow \xi_j$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. Now we have
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k |\xi_j^{(m)} - \xi_j^{(n)}|^p<\epsilon^p\;(1)
$$
and by letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ one obtains for $m>N$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k |\xi_j^{(m)} - \xi_j|^p\leq\epsilon^p.\;(2)
$$

Besides the obvious ($a<b$ implies $a\leq b$), what is the insistence of the author to stress that the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ converts the "<" in (1) to  "$\leq$" in (2)? More specifically, what is the *proof* to go from (1) to (2)?

Comment: (2) is the *limit* of (1) as $n\to\infty.$ The proof for $1\implies2$ is: the limit of any converging positive ($>0$) sequence is $\ge0.$

Comment: This answers your question: [Problems with the proof that $\ell^p$ is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096253/problems-with-the-proof-that-ellp-is-complete): your problem was one of those raised there, and solved by the accepted answer (in the same way as in the comment above).